# converting javascript to PHP: array and objects

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

I want to transform the following javascript code into PHP but I get stuck.
This is the javascript:

```js
var string = "(Munich:0.1,Paris:0.2,(Cyprus:0.3,Brussels:0.4)Bern:0.5)Hamburg";

var ancestors = [];
var tree = {};
var tokens = string.split(/\s*(;|\(|\)|,|:)\s*/);
for (var i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
  var token = tokens[i];
  switch (token) {
    case '(': // new children
      var subtree = {};
      tree.children = [subtree];
      ancestors.push(tree);
      tree = subtree;
      break;
    case ',': // another branch
      var subtree = {};
      ancestors[ancestors.length-1].children.push(subtree);
      tree = subtree;
      break;
    case ')': // optional name next
      tree = ancestors.pop();
      break;
    case ':': // optional length next
      break;
    default:
      var x = tokens[i-1];
      if (x == ')' || x == '(' || x == ',') {
        tree.name = token;
      } else if (x == ':') {
        tree.length = parseFloat(token);
      }
  }
}
```

The output of this (variable tree) is:

```json
{
  name: "Hamburg",
  children: [
    {name: "Munich", length: 0.1},
    {name: "Paris", length: 0.2},
    {
      name: "Bern",
      length: 0.5,
      children: [
        {name: "Cyprus", length: 0.3},
        {name: "Burssels", length: 0.4}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My attempts to convert this into PHP is the below. But the output is completely different. I think it has to do with the differnce in javascript between [] and {} where the one creates an array, the other an object. But I cant get it to work.

```php
$string = "(Munich:0.1,Paris:0.2,(Cyprus:0.3,Brussels:0.4)Bern:0.5)Hamburg";
$ancestors = array();
$tree = array();
$tokens = preg_split('/(:|\,|\(|\))/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$count = count($tokens);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {    
    $token = $tokens[$i];    
    switch ($token) {
        case '(': // new children
            $subtree = array();
            $tree['children'] = $subtree;
            array_push($ancestors, $tree);
            $tree = $subtree;
            break;
        case ',': // another branch
            $subtree = array();
            array_push($ancestors[((count($ancestors))-1)]['children'],$subtree);
            $tree = $subtree;
            break;
       case ')': // optional name next
           $tree = array_pop($ancestors);
           break;
       case ':': // optional length next
           break;
       default:
           $x = $tokens[$i-1];
           if ($x == ')' || $x == '(' || $x == ',') {
               $tree['name'] = $token;
           } else if ($x == ':') {
               $tree['length'] = $token;
           }
    }    
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this are highly appreciated.

Comment: References in php are different than in javascript. Also check out the array append feature. You don't need to do count minus 1, just use brackets with nothing inside.

Comment: You could drop the entire thing and just convert your input string to parsable JSON, assuming you have some idea of what kinds of strings your input string will contain.

Comment: What about converting your string to JSON and then decoding it with the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) function?

Comment: @meagar Sometimes I do not see the forrest... So of course you are perfectly right. The string actually is pretty close to be a json anyway (just with other symbols.) So I have simply replaced some characters and used json_decode. Perfect ! Thanks guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code and it produces the right result

```
<?php

$string = '(Munich:0.1,Paris:0.2,(Cyprus:0.3,Brussels:0.4)Bern:0.5)Hamburg';

$items = parse_code($string);

print_r($items);

function parse_code($string) {
    $data = [];

    if (preg_match_all('@(\((.*)\))*(\w+)(:([0-9.]+))*@', $string, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[2] as $n=>$item) {
            $node = [];

            $node['name'] = $matches[3][$n];

            if ($matches[5][$n]) {
                $node['length'] = $matches[5][$n];
            }

            $children = parse_code($matches[2][$n]);

            if (count($children)) {
                $node['children'] = $children;
            }

            $data[] = $node;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Hamburg
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Munich
                            [length] => 0.1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Paris
                            [length] => 0.2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Bern
                            [length] => 0.5
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Cyprus
                                            [length] => 0.3
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Brussels
                                            [length] => 0.4
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

EDIT: This code works only if you have one nested structure in the current level.

Comment: Instead of `[0-9.]+` I'd use `\d+\.?\d*` which should prevent invalid formats such as `1.2.3`, but looks good otherwise

Comment: Hello Vladimir. Yes you solution works. But the remarks from brainware, meagar and YannBetrand were very important. I have posted my reply to them above.